# Copy/paste changing date format in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to copy/paste a spreadsheet that my employee has created into the main spreadsheet residing on my computer.  When I do so, the date column in the employee spreadsheet changes to a random 6 digit number when pasted in to the big spreadsheet.  I have tried format painter, confirming date format in that column, paste special.  How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Before you copy the data, have you verified the formatting in the column of the "employee" sheet is formatted the same as the sheet you are copying too?

Comment: Select one of the cells and see what you see in the formula bar. Maybe it contains a formula.

Answer (score 0):

Excel [stores dates as a sequential number, starting with the number 1 for the date 1 January 1900](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349).

You say you're seeing 6-digit numbers. The smallest 6-digit number is 100000, which in the 1900 date system represents the date 14 October 2173.

I don't know what data your employee spreadsheet contains, but unless you're actually expecting the data to contain a date so far in the future as the year 2173, this suggests there's something other than a literal date in those cells.

In other words, it's not the *format* that's the problem, but the actual cell contents, which may be a formula involving a reference to a cell that contains something different in your worksheet from what it contains in the employee spreadsheet.

To find out what data's actually causing the problem, click a cell, and look in the formula bar to see the raw contents of the cell.

Do this in both spreadsheets (the employee sheet, and your master sheet).